# Implementing a method to load images from the backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am trying to implement a method to load images from the java backend app. But somehow I am not successful in doing that and idk where is the problem. I will post my code below so that maybe you can point me in a good direction on what is wrong.

I have this in the model file called document.rb

```
 class Image
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :imageId, type: String

    field :image, type: String

    field :name, type: String

    field :teiId, type: String

  end


  def image
    self.external_content['imageId']
  end



 # Return document content which is stored in Java-Backend
  #
  # @return [String] document content
  def external_content
    return unless self.external_document_id

    @content ||= PdsBackend.document(self.external_document_id)
  end
```

and I have this on the view which is of type .haml:

```
%p
= image_tag @document.image
```

any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is getting returned from the java backend, anything or is the issue connecting to that?  It is kind of hard to understand exactly what your issue is.

Comment: @RockwellRice this  "imageId" as "string" is being returned from backend.

Comment: I would think you would need a url or something to show the image but not really sure how you are implementing this.  Where are the images hosted and how are you getting the url to link to the image if the only thing returned is an id?

Comment: @RockwellRice you mean this url : GET /image/{documentId} . That is the case idk if I am doing it right bcz I am not very much experienced in ruby

Comment: no, I am talking about the URL that links to the image in the view.  For example the stackoverflow logo up in the nav above is linked to by this url, `../../Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45` in the css.  When you display the image you need a URL that links to where that image file is being stored, how are you getting that?

Comment: @RockwellRice I edited my question, the image_tag inside the view should take the url of the image which is inside an uploaded document.

Comment: and what is the value of `@document.image` if you just print it out to the view? is it  actually returning a URL?  Can you share the code where the `@document` variable is being created?

Comment: @RockwellRice I changed my code now slightly but the `image_tag` is returning always this url `GET http://localhost:3001/images/` and I want `/image/` not `/images/` any idea why?

Comment: well why not just code in the url path for now, at least until it is working, with `"/image/<%= code for image name or whatever %>"`

Comment: @RockwellRice I get `not found` which is strange, bcz I am sure it exists.